# Swift - Custom UIDatePicker format

Tags: ios, swift, uidatepicker

i'd like to change the format of my UIDatePicker so it can like that "Year Month Day Hour(24) Min"

Is there any way to do that ???

Thanks

Comment: Can't you do that with normal date picker choosing both date and time in storyboard

Comment: @SumitOberoi I've already tried but it's taking too much spaces on the view, and I don't know how to reduce the size of the texts font

Answer (score 7):

You Can't Customize your UIDatePicker, Because UIDatePickerMode have four Types of Mode.

```
public enum UIDatePickerMode : Int {
    case Time // Displays hour, minute, and optionally AM/PM designation depending on the locale setting (e.g. 6 | 53 | PM)
    case Date // Displays month, day, and year depending on the locale setting (e.g. November | 15 | 2007)
    case DateAndTime // Displays date, hour, minute, and optionally AM/PM designation depending on the locale setting (e.g. Wed Nov 15 | 6 | 53 | PM)
    case CountDownTimer // Displays hour and minute (e.g. 1 | 53)
}
```

You can display only one of the mode as above.

Answer (score 2):

Here is the code to get the date in your desired format:

```
let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "YYYY-MM-dd HH:mm"
let strDate = dateFormatter.stringFromDate(NSDate()) // You can pass your date here as a parameter to get in a desired format
print(strDate)
```

Answer (score 1):

I've done like this http://sourcefreeze.com/ios-datepicker-tutorial-uidatepicker-using-swift/

```
 var dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
        dateFormatter.dateFormat = "dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm"
        var strDate = dateFormatter.stringFromDate(myDatePicker.date)
        self.selectedDate.text = strDate
```

So, you need "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm"

Answer (score 0):

For SwiftUI enthousiasts, can display the current date and time on the same line like so :

```swiftui
HStack {
  Text(Date(), style: .date)
  Text(Date(), style: .time)
}
```